# How to resolve template error in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Please help me to resolve the following error.When i clicked on new button nothing is happening.There is no page redirecting.Please give me some idea to resolve this error.

Error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `input' for #<ActionView::Helpers:
:FormBuilder:0x46ed500>):
    1: <%= form_for @task, :url => {:action => 'create'},remote: true do |f|   %
>
    2:   <%= f.input  :description  %>
    3:   <%= f.input  :deadline     %>
    4:   <%= f.button :submit      %>
    5: <% end %>
  app/views/tasks/_form.html.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_tasks__form_html_erb_
_264285017_35597352'
  app/views/tasks/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_tasks__form_html_erb__26428501
7_35597352'
  app/views/tasks/new.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_tasks_new_js_erb__302618978_315636
60'


  Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.7/lib/action_dispa
tch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (15.6ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.7/lib/action_dispa
tch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.7/lib/action_dispa
tch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.text.erb (15.6ms)
```

My code snippets are given below.:

views/tasks/index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
    <h2>Tasks</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">
    <%= link_to tasks_new_path, remote: true do %>
      <button class="btn btn-default">New</button>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2" id="task-form" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1" id="tasks"><%= render @tasks %></div>
</div>
```

views/tasks/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Its a new page</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

views/tasks/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @task, :url => {:action => 'create'},remote: true do |f|   %>
  <%= f.input  :description  %>
  <%= f.input  :deadline     %>
  <%= f.button :submit      %>
<% end %>
```

views/tasks/new.js.erb

```
$('#task-form').html("<%= j (render 'form') %>");
$('#task-form').slideDown(350);
```

controller/tasks_controller.rb

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
before_action:all_tasks,only: [:index,:create]
respond_to :html, :js
def new
@task = Task.new
end
def create
@task=Task.create(tasks_params)
end
private
def all_tasks
 @tasks = Task.all
end
def tasks_params
 params.require(:task).permit(:description, :deadline)
end
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "tasks#index"
  get "tasks/new" => "tasks#new" 
  post "tasks/create" => "tasks#create"
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You try to use helper `input` coming from `simple_form` gem, but you don't seem to use `simple_form`. I assume these fields should be 'usual' text fields, so you should do:

```
<%= form_for @task, remote: true do |f|   %>
  <%= f.text_field  :description  %>
  <%= f.text_field  :deadline     %>
  <%= f.button :submit      %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't that be

```
<%= form_for @task, :url => {:action => 'create'},remote: true do |f|   %>
  <%= f.text_area  :description  %>
  <%= f.text_field  :deadline     %>
  <%= f.submit   %>
<% end %>
```

That's how the formhelpes normally work.

EDIT: Fixed typo's, autocorrect removed the _ ..